What is the primary function of the phosphorlyation of glucose in the first step of glycolysis?
Some textbooks emphasize that it traps glucose in the cell, but some sources mention glucose "activation." There is a response on Quora that claims that energetics are irrelevant and that phosphorylation solely about trapping glucose.
